# iOS ajax call from a local html to a local xml resource not working

Tags: ios, ajax, uiwebview, nsurlcache

In my iOS app I am loading a local html file which internally is making an ajax call to a local xml resource which is failing. I am using NSURLCache to intercept the request.

Comment: Paste some code and error description, might help.

Comment: Are you using any server or directly opening the html file using browser. If opening directly the xml will not get loaded due to CORS in browser. User server and put both files in same folder..or access he xml file through server ..

Comment: Previously i was opening the html directly in the browser. Using GCDWebServer to host a simple server did the work and opened the html file with localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously i was opening the html directly in the browser. Using GCDWebServer to host a simple server did the work and opened the html file with localhost.